# EndlessScroll using KendoUI Mobile + Azure Mobile Services + SQL Azure

Tags: azure, mobile, endlessscroll

I have been struggling for the past few days with Endless Scrolling on a mobile listview. I have set up my datasource and listview as the demo suggests. I have not been able to successfully get it to work (or 'press to load more' for that matter) on server-side data. The local data works as expected. I have used many different KendoUI core builds and the results are pretty much the same.

One difference I did notice though, is the type: "odata" part in the demo that refuses to work for me (500 Internal Server Error). I therefore tried a normal "GET" type on the datasource. The "GET" was odata-style (https://myserviceapi.azure-mobile.net/tables/EventTypes?$filter=businessID%20eq%2053) which is supported out of the box on Azure Tables, but endless scrolling did not work. I also tried a normal "GET" of an Azure Mobile Services api method that is basically a RESTful method that returns the same data as the odata table query in SQL Azure. None of the things I have tried work. The following code is what I have and tested with many Kendo UI Core builds.

App JavaScript:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({

                                                   transport: {

                                                                       read: {

                                                                                     url: 'https://myserviceapi.azure-mobile.net/tables/EventTypes?$filter=businessID%20eq%20' + busID,

                                                                                    dataType: "json"

                                                                                 }

                                                                   },

                                                   serverPaging: true,

                                                   pageSize: 12

 });







$("#photoHolder").kendoMobileListView({  

                                              dataSource: dataSource,

                                              template: "<p>#: eventName #</p>",

                                              endlessScrolling: true,

                                              filterable:{

            field: "eventName",

            operator: "contains",

            ignoreCase: true,

            placeholder: "search products..."

        }

 });
```

HTML:

```
<ul  id="photoHolder" data-role="listview">

</ul>
```

Azure JavaScript:

```
    exports.get = function(request, response) {

    var mssql = request.service.mssql;

    var cnt = request.query.pageSize;

    var pnm = request.query.page;



    var sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY zOrder) AS RowNum, * FROM myschema.EventTypes where (businessID = " + request.query.busID + ") and active = 1) AS E " +

        "WHERE RowNum BETWEEN ((" + pnm + " - 1) * cnt + 1) AND (" + pnm + " * " + cnt + ") ORDER BY zOrder";



    mssql.query(sql, {

        success: function(results) {

            response.send(200, results);

        },

        error: function(err) {

            console.log(err);

            response.send(530, { error: err });

        }

    });

};
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to this when I was playing around on my own "pet" app. I just had to make sure that there were enough items in the list to actually give that endless scroll experience. In the Kendo UI forums, they suggest a pageSize of at least 30. {http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile/listview/endless-scrolling}

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks @SuperBiasedMan. I am new to StackOverflow and finding my around the conventions. I will try my best to follow them to the fullest.